# When reading a file in java using a scanner, previous elements get overwritten by the latest one, why does that happen?

Tags: java, arrays

```js
File info = new File("..\\userInfo2\\users.txt");
        Scanner size = new Scanner(info);
        Scanner read = new Scanner(info);
        read.useDelimiter(",");
        size.useDelimiter(",");
        
        String ID[], name[], password[];
        int count = 0, sub = 0;
        
        //finds array size
        while(size.hasNext())
        {
            count ++;
            size.next();    //if nextLine(), then # of lines
        }

        name = ID = password = new String [count];
```

```
for (int i = 0; read.hasNext(); i++) {
    name[i] = read.next();
    read.next();
    ID[i] = read.next();
    password[i]= read.next();
    read.next();
    read.next();

    System.out.println(name[i] + ID[i] + password[i]);
}
```

name[i] and ID[i] keep getting overwritten. in the end I always get password[i] three times. Why does this happen and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You are changing the index in the arrays during each iteration, so I will guess that the problem has something to do with your use of the scanner.

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: I added the first part.

Comment: `name = ID = password = new String [count];` only makes one array. All 3 variables are referring to the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name, ID and password are reference variables that all point to the same object. Hence any change done to any one of them is reflected on the others.

Comment: So by doing name = ID = password = new String [count], I did not create 3 arrays with the same capacity, but 3 references to the same location?

Comment: Exactly! Better do 3 separate declarations.